# I need to distanciate element in form bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I need to distantiate element in a form bootstrap.

My code is:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="label_test_email">Send email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test_email" name="test_email" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="bottone_test_email" value="Test Email"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

I need to distantiate element, anyone can help me?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I don't know what "distanciate" means.

Comment: Which element? distance from what?

Comment: What do you have tried so far? Please, show us in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more distance between the field-set and the button just do something like:

```
<style>
.form-inline .form-control{
  margin-right:1em;
}
</style>
```

If you need distance between the label and the field as well, do:

```
<style>
.form-control{
  margin-right:2em;
}
.form-group label{
  margin-right:1em;
}      
</style>
```